# Python tinker non blocking message box multithreading

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Try to create simple non blocking message box in tinker so it will display information and program get completed as I preferred messagebox concept of Window

my code is following

```
import threading
from disp_message import disp_message

msg =" This is a test message"
msgtype = 1

t1 = threading.Thread(target=disp_message, args=(msg,msgtype,))
t1.start()
t1.join()

for i in range(100000):
    print(i)
disp_message(msg,msgtype)
print("Done!")

disp_messagee function code is

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def disp_message(msg,msgtype):
    top = Tk()
    top.withdraw()
    if msgtype==1:
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning",msg)
    elif msgtype==2:
         messagebox.showinfo("information",msg)
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error",msg)
```

when I am running a program it is giving me following error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "toto.py", line 13, in <module>
    disp_message(msg,msgtype)
  File "c:\NSE\scripts\disp_message.py", line 8, in disp_message
    messagebox.showwarning("Warning",msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\messagebox.py", line 87, in showwarning
    return _show(title, message, WARNING, OK, **options)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\messagebox.py", line 72, in _show
    res = Message(**options).show()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\commondialog.py", line 39, in show
    w = Frame(self.master)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2744, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

and secondly it does not display tkinter message box in parallel

Can you pl help me ? secondly not sure where t1.join() is required or not as my objective is to just display message and execute program completely.

Comment: what is `disp_message` in `from disp_message import disp_message`?

Comment: disp_message is a function written in another python file

Comment: Your error is a typo in this line: `t1 = threading.Thread(target=disp_mssage, args=(msg,msgtype,))`, and is of course repeated in the error!

Comment: Thanks for correction, but still it does not solve the problem it is not running messagebox parallelly and it give me following error

Comment: edited question thans

Comment: It is better to ask a new question rather than modifying the original question by correcting mistakes pointed out to you. `tkinter` does not support threading; all `tkinter` elements must be in the main thread. Please ask a new question if you still have problems.

Comment: OK @Reblochon Masque I will ask new question