# python tkinter non blocking information

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create non-blocking tkiner messagebox using multithreading. I know messagebox is not defined in this way, but I preferred the messagebox concept and functions. I am having actual main program which is quite large and complex so showing some example

program toto.py

```
import threading
from disp_message import disp_message

msg =" This is a test message"
msgtype = 1

t1 = threading.Thread(target=disp_message, args=(msg,msgtype,))
t1.start()
t1.join()

for i in range(100000):
    print(i)
disp_message(msg,msgtype)
print("Done!")

disp_messagee  python function code in another file

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def disp_message(msg,msgtype):
    top = Tk()
    top.withdraw()
    if msgtype==1:
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning",msg)
    elif msgtype==2:
         messagebox.showinfo("information",msg)
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error",msg)
```

When I run this program i am having 2 issues
1. Following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "toto.py", line 13, in <module>
    disp_message(msg,msgtype)
  File "c:\NSE\scripts\disp_message.py", line 8, in disp_message
    messagebox.showwarning("Warning",msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\messagebox.py", line 87, in showwarning
    return _show(title, message, WARNING, OK, **options)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\messagebox.py", line 72, in _show
    res = Message(**options).show()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\commondialog.py", line 39, in show
    w = Frame(self.master)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2744, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

2. Secondly it displays messagebox and wait for acknowledgement.

While my objective is to display messagebox and parallel let program get executed and finished.

Can you pl help ?

Comment: Have you considered moving the non-tkinter code into the thread? Tkinter needs to be running in the main thread, just as the error states.

Comment: How is this question different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58003271/python-tinker-non-blocking-message-box-multithreading?

Comment: @Bryan it will be great help if you can show in above example itself

Comment: Hi Any help on this ?